# MySQL query for finding relation between three tables with constraints, even if the relation doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on an online university that has users, courses, and user to course status. I have a list of users, and another list of courses. I want to find the course status for all of the given users and courses, including null status for a course that a user hasn't yet started.

So for example:

```
User IDs: [1, 7, 14, 21]  
Course IDs: [5, 8, 36, 50]
```

Desired result:

```
Name        Course                     Status
 John Doe    How to Tie your Shoes      Complete
 John Doe    How to Paint your House    In Progress
 Jane Doe    How to Tie your Shoes      Complete
 Jane Doe    How to Paint your House    Not Started <-- These are the tricky ones
```

...

It seems that I can perform a LEFT JOIN on the tables and get some NULL values, which I can coalesce into 'Not Started' but as soon as I add some constraints to limit which courses and/or users I'm looking for...it stops giving me NULL values values because a NULL course ID clearly isn't in my list of courses above.

Here's an example query giving you an idea of what I've been trying (among other things):

```
SELECT
    `users`.`name` AS `Name`,
    `users`.`email` AS `Email`,
    `courses`.`number` AS `Course #`,
    `courses`.`name` AS `Course`,
    COALESCE(`courses_users_statuses`.`name`, 'Not Started') AS `Status`
FROM
    `users`
    LEFT JOIN `courses_users` 
        ON `courses_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `courses` 
        ON `courses`.`id` = `courses_users`.`course_id`
    LEFT JOIN `courses_users_statuses` 
        ON `courses_users_statuses`.`id` = `courses_users`.`status_id`
WHERE
    `courses`.`id` IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 16, ...])
    AND `users`.`id` IN ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 21, 36, 48, ...])
ORDER BY
    `users`.`name`,
    `courses`.`number`
```

Any ideas on how to write something like this? Also, let me know if I can provide any more detail or more code/table examples.

EDIT: Here's my updated query using advice from the answers below:

```
SELECT
    `users`.`name` AS `Name`,
    `users`.`email` AS `Email`,
    `courses`.`number` AS `Course #`,
    `courses`.`name` AS `Course`,
    COALESCE(`courses_users_statuses`.`name`, 'Not Started') AS `Status`
FROM
    `users`
        LEFT JOIN
    `courses_users` ON `courses_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
        LEFT JOIN
    `courses` ON `courses`.`id` = `courses_users`.`course_id` AND `courses`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
        LEFT JOIN
    `courses_users_statuses` ON `courses_users_statuses`.`id` = `courses_users`.`status_id`
WHERE
    `users`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ORDER BY
    `partners`.`name`,
    `users`.`name`,
    `courses`.`number`
```

This updated example is an improvement, but now it's showing records where there is no course name or number, but there IS a status. I'm not sure how it's grabbing a status for course relations that should exist. Instead those should be NULL (or "Not Started"). Here's some sample data from the database:

`` `users` `` table:

```
id    name             email
1     Stevie McComb    test@example.com
2     John Doe         test@example.org
3     Jane Doe         test@example.net
```

`` `courses` `` table:

```
id    number    name
1     101       Navigation
2     102       Logging In
3     103       Updating Records
4     104       Managing Users
```

`` `courses_users` `` table:

```
course_id    user_id    status_id    completed_at
1            1          2            2017-01-01 00:00:00
3            1          1            2017-01-05 00:23:00
1            2          2            2017-04-13 15:00:37
```

`` `courses_users_statuses` `` table:

```
id    name           slug
1     In Progress    progress
2     Complete       complete
```

Desired Result:

```
Name             Email               Course #    Course              Status
Stevie McComb    test@example.com    101         Navigation          Complete
Stevie McComb    test@example.com    102         Logging In          Not Started
Stevie McComb    test@example.com    103         Updating Records    In Progress
Stevie McComb    test@example.com    104         Managing Users      Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org    101         Navigation          Complete
John Doe         test@example.org    102         Logging In          Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org    103         Updating Records    Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org    104         Managing Users      Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net    101         Navigation          Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net    102         Logging In          Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net    103         Updating Records    Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net    104         Managing Users      Not Started
```

Current Result:

```
Name             Email               Course #    Course              Status
Stevie McComb    test@example.com                                    Complete
Stevie McComb    test@example.com                                    Not Started
Stevie McComb    test@example.com    103         Updating Records    In Progress
Stevie McComb    test@example.com                                    Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org    101         Navigation          Complete
John Doe         test@example.org                                    Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org                                    Not Started
John Doe         test@example.org                                    Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net                                    Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net                                    Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net                                    Not Started
Jane Doe         test@example.net                                    Not Started
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're putting the constraints in your where clause, without allowing for a `null` value.. This essentially changes the `left join` back to an `inner join`.

To fix this, you can either explicitly allow for nulls, or you can move the logic to the join clause (my preference).

```
select
    `users`.`name` as `name`,
    `users`.`email` as `email`,
    `courses`.`number` as `course #`,
    `courses`.`name` as `course`,
    coalesce(`courses_users_statuses`.`name`, 'not started') as `status`
from
    `users`
    left join `courses_users` 
        on `courses_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
    left join `courses` 
        on `courses`.`id`   = `courses_users`.`course_id`
        and `courses`.`id` in ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 16, ...])
    left join `courses_users_statuses` 
        on `courses_users_statuses`.`id` = `courses_users`.`status_id`
where
    `users`.`id` in ([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 20, 21, 36, 48, ...])
order by
    `users`.`name`,
    `courses`.`number`
```

Comment: I totally forgot that you could add constraints to a join. That just might solve the problem. I'll try this out today once I get a change to work on the project again and let you know if I run into any other issues.

Comment: @StevieMcComb: If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/accepting the answers as appropriate. I only mention this since you're new and [may not know](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I didn't get a chance to work on this project again until this morning. This got me closer as it's returning null values in areas where it wasn't before...but now it's causing me a new headache. There are records being returned that are randomly lacking the course names and/or numbers. This is even happening where the course status is "Complete" or "In Progress", meaning that there's not a null value there, but for some reason the course details are missing. For example:  

Name => 'John Doe',
Course # => ,
Course Name => ,
Status => 'Complete'

Comment: It sounds like those users have not taken the specified course. The way you've defined the query will return all users whose IDs are entered, whether or not they took the course at all.

Comment: Which is intended, but there are multiple courses per user. So it should list the given course names/numbers as well even if the user hasn't taken them, showing a "Not Started" or NULL value for the status. But instead its showing a status but no course name. I'm not sure where it's getting the "Started" or "In Progress" status from for courses that a user hasn't attempted. Those should be NULL, but they're not always. I've checked the tables and the data is all good, but for some reason the query is getting confused. I've updated the question with my most recent query.

Comment: @StevieMcComb: Please edit your question to include a sample of the data and the results you're getting.

Comment: Just did right before you posted that. Sorry, should have done that first.

Comment: @StevieMcComb: I don't see data added, just a query.

Comment: My bad, I didn't add sample data, just an update query. I've updated my question now with sample data and a sample query result as well. Took me a minute to type it all up and format it.

Answer (score 0):

When I have to deal with potentially NULL values, I use

```
IFNULL(field_name, 'use this value instead');
```

For instance

```
SELECT
IFNULL(Course, 'Nothing Found') AS course
FROM
Course
Where....
```

Or you could specify in your WHERE clause...

```
WHERE Course IS NOT NULL
```